# How to transform a particular column to row

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape, dcast

I want to restructure my data that looks like the left table to the right one, which I would like to transform to.

[image]

The above sample data in the left table is coded as follows.

```
data <- data.frame(country=c('US', 'US', 'US', 'US', 'US', 'UO', 'UO', 'UO', 'UO', 'UO'),
               year=c(2015, 2015, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2016, 2016),
               region=c('NY', 'CA', 'MI', 'MA', 'IL', 'GH', 'FD', 'AH', 'PO', 'LQ'))
```

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Use dplyr and purrr packages to solve this problem

```
#collection of many packagaes like tibble,dplyr,purrr,ggplot and etc.
library(tidyverse) 
data %>%
    #First two columns contain grouping variables
    group_by(year,country) %>%
    #based on grouping variables, make other columns into a list and store 
    #them in an other column
    nest() %>%
    #map is from purrr package, which can deal with list in a dataframe
    # t() transpose the dataframe, as.tibble() make them into tibble class
    mutate(data = map(data,~ as.tibble(t(.x)))) %>%
    #unnest the list column
    unnest() %>%
    #rename columns
    rename(region1 = V1, region2 = V2, region3 = V3)
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
   year country region1 region2 region3
  <dbl> <fct>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
1  2015 US      NY      CA      NA     
2  2016 US      MI      MA      IL     
3  2015 UO      GH      FD      AH     
4  2016 UO      PO      LQ      NA
```

Replace NA with an empty string "" if you want.

---

Or rename in this way:

```
library(stringr)
colnames(temp) <- str_replace(colnames(temp),pattern = fixed("V"),replacement = "region")           
colnames(temp)
#result
[1] "year"    "country" "region1" "region2" "region3"
```

Comment: Thank you very much Yifu Yan for your help and the excellent codes.